# SQLite: Two different Counts on different table

Tags: sqlite, count

I am pretty sure you guys have a simple and fast solution to my problem but my SQL-Skills are limited and I can't figure it out by my self.

So what I have is something like:

Newsgroup: [Name(PK)]

Article: [Id(PK)] [newsgroupName (FK)] [date:Date] [read:Boolean]

What I want know is a query that gives me the Name of each Newsgroup along with the Count of unread articles, Count of all articles and the date of the most recent one...
Is this even possible to archieve in a single Select-Query?

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the appropriate aggregation functions:

```
SELECT newsgroupName,
       SUM(NOT read) AS countUnread,
       COUNT(*)      AS countAll,
       MAX(date)     AS mostRecentDate
FROM Article
GROUP BY newsgroupName;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for! The only thing i will have to look at is the Performance hit if I implement this in an android application with room database and liveobjects. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(countUnread) AS countUnread, COUNT(countRead) AS countRead, MAX(mostRecentDateUnread) AS mostRecentDateUnread, MAX(mostRecentDateRead) AS mostRecentDateRead FROM (
    SELECT newsgroupName AS name, COUNT(newsgroupName) AS countUnread, 0 AS countRead, MAX(date) AS mostRecentDateUnread, NULL AS mostRecentDateRead
    FROM Article
    WHERE read = 0
    GROUP BY newsgroupName, read

    UNION ALL

    SELECT newsgroupName AS name, 0 AS countUnread, COUNT(newsgroupName) AS countRead, NULL AS mostRecentDateUnread, MAX(date) AS mostRecentDateRead
    FROM Article
    WHERE read = 1
    GROUP BY newsgroupName, read
)
GROUP BY name
```

I haven't tried but in theory with some fix it could work.

Comment: Does this include the count of all articles and all unread ones?

Comment: @HugoCodes sorry, I missed that part. Have a look now.

Comment: Thanks! I will check if that works as soon as I am back home. I don't need the date of the unread/read articles tho.. only the last ;) But i think i can figure that out by my self. Are there any potential performance problems regarding the inner select?